# Wordpress DB select always returns empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I made a custom function to select data from database using WP methods.  It looks like this;

```
function CheckUser($name){
                /*DB connection */
                $result = $mydb->get_results("SELECT *FROM users WHERE name = ".$name.";");
                if(!empty($result)){
                    echo "OK!";
                }
        }
```

And here is a part in code:

```
/*This part is in foreach so thats why I am using $obj
$name_string = $obj->first_name." ".$obj->surname;
Prombutne($name_string);
```

But every time I not receive anything from DataBase, when I change *!empty* to *empty* I get OK so  Select function always return's empty.

Comment: Do you get a result if you remove the WHERE clause?

Comment: Yes, also get a result if I put username manually not pass it like a variable.

Comment: You should use a parameter instead to pass the value.

Comment: Try this: $result = $mydb->get_results("SELECT *FROM users WHERE name = '$name'");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
$result = $mydb->get_results("SELECT *FROM users WHERE name = ".$name.";");
```

with

```
$result = $mydb->get_results("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '".$name."'");
```

You have to give space after '*' and before 'table_name' and in where condition you are using name field which is string so you need to pass it in quotes.